# Perl XML to tab delimited text file with XSLT (or not)

Tags: xml, perl, xslt

Novice Perl programmer, trying to convert simple xml string to a **tab delimited text file**.
I struggled with using XML::Parser (and XML::Twig/Simple and even XSLT), but I couldn't figure out how to get the main data parts to be the column headings.

Then I started trying to do it with XSLT, but I can't figure out how to get a separator between the elements -- (then I would just use split and/or join?) but they all just run together in one string.

I just manually printed the column headings manually. Is there an easy way to do that with the template?

Similar questions I looked at, but couldn't see any separators being added to my files. [XML to Tab delimited Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291694/xml-to-tab-delimited-text)
[Modifying a XSLT for converting XML to tab delimited text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912900/modifying-a-xslt-for-converting-xml-to-tab-delimited-text-file)

Questions:

1. What's the easiest way to do this, generally, and should I be even using XSLT (which I've been trying to understand).
2. How can I fix the below to do this?

It seems like I'm close but only need to get a delimiter into the XSLT output string so I can split it and then join it with "\t" in my output to tab-delimited text file. ??

This is my XML (SMS logs from Twilio):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <TwilioResponse>
     <SMSMessages end="49" firstpageuri="/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACcbaa0/SMS/Messages?Page=0&amp;PageSize=50" lastpageuri="/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACcbaa/SMS/Messages?Page=54&amp;PageSize=50" nextpageuri="/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACcbaa0103c/SMS/Messages?Page=1&amp;PageSize=50&amp;AfterSid=SMc20cf7" numpages="55" page="0" pagesize="50" previouspageuri="" start="0" total="2703" uri="/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACcbaa0103cf/SMS/Messages">
        <SMSMessage>
           <Sid>SMe24eb108b7eb6a3b</Sid>
           <DateCreated>Fri, 09 Aug 2013 00:07:59 +0000</DateCreated>
           <DateUpdated>Fri, 09 Aug 2013 00:07:59 +0000</DateUpdated>
           <DateSent>Fri, 09 Aug 2013 00:07:59 +0000</DateSent>
           <AccountSid>ACcbaa0103c4141e5cd754042cb424d4ff</AccountSid>
           <To>+14444444444</To>
           <From>+15555555555</From>
           <Body>Hi there!</Body>
           <Status>sent</Status>
           <Direction>outbound-api</Direction>
           <Price>-0.01000</Price>
           <PriceUnit>USD</PriceUnit>
           <ApiVersion>2010-04-01</ApiVersion>
           <Uri>/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACcbaa01/SMS/Messages/SMe24eb108b</Uri>
        </SMSMessage>
        <SMSMessage>
            ... etc. ...
        </SMSMessage>
     </SMSMessages>
  </TwilioResponse>
```

This is the XSLT I was trying to use:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
   <xsl:template match="//TwilioResponse">
   <xsl:for-each select="SMSMessage">
       <xsl:value-of select="Sid"/>
       <!-- I tried all these, too: &#x20   &#x9;  even &#xA;   -->
       <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
       <!-- I also tried this from another SO question -->
       <xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if>
       <xsl:value-of select="DateCreated"/>
       <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="DateUpdated"/>
       <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="DateSent"/>
       <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="AccountSid"/>
       <xsl:text>&#09;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:text>&#x20;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="To"/>
       <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="From"/>
       <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="Body"/>
       <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="Status"/>
       <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="Direction"/>
       <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="Price"/>
       <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="PriceUnit"/>
       <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="ApiVersion"/>
       <xsl:text>&#x9;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="Uri"/>
       <!-- I tried both of these: line feed char -->
       <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is the relevant part of my Perl code:

```
use XML::XSLT;

my $logs = $twilio -> GET ('SMS/Messages');
my $string = $logs->{content};

my $xsl = 'xsl.txt';
my $xslt = XML::XSLT->new ($xsl);
$xslt->transform ($string);
my $xsltToString = $xslt->toString;

    print $xsltToString;

my $columnHeadings = "Sid\tDateCreated\tDateUpdated\tDateSent\tAccountSid\tTo\tFrom\tBody\tStatus\tDirection\tPrice\tPriceUnit\tApiVersion\tUri\n";

open(my $fh, '>', 'textfile.txt') || die("Unable to open file. $!");
    print $fh  $columnHeadings;
    foreach my $k (@split) {
        print $fh join("\t", $xsltToString) . "\t";
    }       
        #print $fh split("\t", $val). "\t"; ;
close($fh);
$xslt->dispose();


# P.S. I'm sure there's a better way to check and see how many lines were saved.

my $xmllines = 0;
open $fh, '<', 'textfile.txt' or die "Could not open file. $!";
   while (<$fh>) {
      $xmllines++;
   }
print ("\n" . $xmllines . " lines saved to tab-delimited logs textfile. \n");   
close $fh;
```

My output is all one thing with no separation between any of the elements.

Comment: If I run `XML::Simple` to parse your XML, I get a nice little incomprehensible data structure that should contain the data you want to create a tab delimited file. What's the problem?

Comment: `perl -MXML::Simple -MData::Dumper -lwe"print Dumper XMLin(shift)" yourfile.xml`

Comment: If you view your output file in an editor or such for example, you wont see the tab delimiter spacing, but it is in place..

Comment: @TLP Perhaps I should have posted what I was trying when I did that. I guess I will, b/c I want to know why I wasn't able to get it into what I wanted there, either. Is it just a matter of writing the specific hash references out in the order you want them? Thanks!

Comment: @hwnd - ahh! But then shouldn't excel be able to import it?

Comment: @hwnd - When I import to excel it doesn't recognize any tabs, and it puts it all in one huge cell.

Comment: @TLP - I know, but I wanted all the <SMSMessage>'s only, with the data elements as column headings. I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd think XSLT is the wrong tool for this problem: It is awesome for XML→XML transformations, but too verbose for this XML→CSV transformation. Instead of applying an XSLT style, we can use Perl’s [`XML::LibXML`](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML) module or something comparable to parse the XML and apply XPath queries, and [`Text::CSV`](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV) to emit the data to a file.

```perl
use strict; use warnings;
use autodie;
use XML::LibXML;
use Text::CSV;

# Parse the XML
my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => ...);

# Prepare the CSV
open my $csv_fh, ">:utf8", "textfile.csv";
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
  binary => 1,
  eol => "\n",
  # sep_char => "\t", # for tab separation. Default is comma
  # quote_space => 0, # makes tab seperated data look better.
});

my @columns = qw/
  Sid
  DateCreated  DateUpdated  DateSent
  AccountSid
  To  From  Body
  Status
  Direction
  Price  PriceUnit
  ApiVersion
  Uri
/;

$csv->print($csv_fh, \@columns);  # print the header

# loop through all messages. Note that `print` wants an arrayref.
for my $sms ($xml->findnodes('//SMSMessage')) {
  $csv->print($csv_fh, [ map { $sms->findvalue("./$_") } @columns ]);
}
```

Output:

```
Sid,DateCreated,DateUpdated,DateSent,AccountSid,To,From,Body,Status,Direction,Price,PriceUnit,ApiVersion,Uri
SMe24eb108b7eb6a3b,"Fri, 09 Aug 2013 00:07:59 +0000","Fri, 09 Aug 2013 00:07:59 +0000","Fri, 09 Aug 2013 00:07:59 +0000",ACcbaa0103c4141e5cd754042cb424d4ff,+14444444444,+15555555555,"Hi there!",sent,outbound-api,-0.01000,USD,2010-04-01,/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACcbaa01/SMS/Messages/SMe24eb108b
,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Or the tab-separated version:

```
Sid     DateCreated     DateUpdated     DateSent        AccountSid      To      From    Body   Status   Direction       Price   PriceUnit       ApiVersion      Uri
SMe24eb108b7eb6a3b      Fri, 09 Aug 2013 00:07:59 +0000 Fri, 09 Aug 2013 00:07:59 +0000 Fri, 09 Aug 2013 00:07:59 +0000 ACcbaa0103c4141e5cd754042cb424d4ff      +14444444444    +15555555555   Hi there!        sent    outbound-api    -0.01000        USD     2010-04-01      /2010-04-01/Accounts/ACcbaa01/SMS/Messages/SMe24eb108b
```

(last line does not show)

Note that using CSV with any separator char is probably a bad idea: What happens when the message contains newlines or tabs? The basic [GSM 03.38 charset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38) includes at least LF and CR characters.

#### Edit: further explanations

The `\` is a reference operator, so `\@columns` is an array reference pointing to the `@columns` array.

The `map` function takes a block of code and a list. Like a `foreach` loop, it executes this block for each value in the list. In each iteration, the `$_` variable is set to the current element. Unlike the `foreach` loop, `map` returns a list of values. This makes it suitable for transformations. E.g to double some numbers:

```
my @doubles = map { $_ * 2 } 1 .. 5; #=> 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
```

The `findvalue` method of DOM nodes applies an XPath expression in the context of this node and returns the text value of the found element. The XPath expression `./foo` is equivalent to `foo`, and searches for a child element called `foo`. We use the `$_` variable to denote the column name/tag name. So the map expression

```
map { $sms->findvalue("./$_") } @columns
```

transforms the list of columns to a list of text values. I used the form `./foo` for the XPath expression because I think it better conveys the meaning “give me an immediate child (`/`) with the tag name `foo` of *this* SMS (`.`)”, especially when one is used to the notation of file paths.

The `[ ... ]` operator is a way to create an array reference from the list inside. E.g. `[1, 2, 3]` is a shortcut for

```
  my @temp = (1, 2, 3);
  \@temp;
```

(note the `\` operator again).

Comment: Awesome - thanks! 
1. Re:  \@columns in $csv->print($csv_fh, \@columns);  # print the header. Is that a perl thing or do I look in docs for Text::CSV?

2. What is "./$_"? I think I understand $_ most of the time, but what does ./ add, here?

3. Are the [ ] around [ map { $sms->findvalue("./$_") } @columns ] so that whatever "it" is, becomes an array reference?

Comment: @BradFallon I updated with more explanations. **TL;DR:** (1) This `print` method is documented in Text::CSV. It needs an array reference, which we produce with the `\ ` operator. (2) Unneccessary XPath syntax. (3) yes.

Comment: Great answer, but instead of `$sms->findvalue("./$_")`, you can simply write `$sms->findvalue($_)`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example using [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML%3a%3aTwig):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Const::Fast;
use Text::CSV;
use XML::Twig;

run({
    csv => Text::CSV->new({
        always_quote => 1,
        binary => 1,
    }),
    in_fh => \*DATA,
    out_fh => \*STDOUT,
    wanted_fields => [
        qw(
            Sid
            DateCreated
            DateUpdated
            DateSent
            AccountSid
            To
            From
            Body
            Status
            Direction
            Price
            PriceUnit
            ApiVersion
            Uri
        )
    ],
});

sub run {
    my $args = shift;
    my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
        twig_roots => {
            SMSMessage => sub { print_csv($args, @_) },
        }
    );
    $twig->parse($args->{in_fh});
}

sub print_csv {
    my $args = shift;
    my $twig = shift;
    my $elt = shift;
    my %fields = map { $_->name, $_->text } $elt->children;

    my $csv = $args->{csv};
    my $wanted = $args->{wanted_fields};
    $csv->combine(@fields{ @{$args->{wanted_fields}} });

    print { $args->{out_fh} } $csv->string, "\n";
    $twig->purge;
    return;
}

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <TwilioResponse>
     <SMSMessages end="49" firstpageuri="/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACcbaa0/SMS/Messages?Page=0&amp;PageSize=50" lastpageuri="/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACcbaa/SMS/Messages?Page=54&amp;PageSize=50" nextpageuri="/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACcbaa0103c/SMS/Messages?Page=1&amp;PageSize=50&amp;AfterSid=SMc20cf7" numpages="55" page="0" pagesize="50" previouspageuri="" start="0" total="2703" uri="/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACcbaa0103cf/SMS/Messages">
        <SMSMessage>
           <Sid>SMe24eb108b7eb6a3b</Sid>
           <DateCreated>Fri, 09 Aug 2013 00:07:59 +0000</DateCreated>
           <DateUpdated>Fri, 09 Aug 2013 00:07:59 +0000</DateUpdated>
           <DateSent>Fri, 09 Aug 2013 00:07:59 +0000</DateSent>
           <AccountSid>ACcbaa0103c4141e5cd754042cb424d4ff</AccountSid>
           <To>+14444444444</To>
           <From>+15555555555</From>
           <Body>Hi there!</Body>
           <Status>sent</Status>
           <Direction>outbound-api</Direction>
           <Price>-0.01000</Price>
           <PriceUnit>USD</PriceUnit>
           <ApiVersion>2010-04-01</ApiVersion>
           <Uri>/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACcbaa01/SMS/Messages/SMe24eb108b</Uri>
        </SMSMessage>
        <SMSMessage>
            ... etc. ...
        </SMSMessage>
     </SMSMessages>
  </TwilioResponse>
```